# SilverStripe 3.4+ How to show child pages in the menu from every level 1 page?

Tags: templates, navigation, silverstripe

I'm trying to build a menu which shows the level 1 menu and also the level 2 menu on the same navigation bar. This is because all the children of Page 1 need to be in the top level menu. I can easily do this by looping menu(2) in the nav, but this only shows those pages if you are on the parent page.

```
    <% loop $Menu(2) %>
            <li class="$LinkingMode"><a href="$Link" title="$Title.XML">$MenuTitle.XML</a></li>
        <% end_loop %>
    <% loop $Menu(1) %>
        <li class="$LinkingMode"><a href="$Link" title="$Title.XML">$MenuTitle.XML</a></li>
    <% end_loop %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can loop the children of a menu using $Children

If you just want the entire list of all the child pages, you can loop the menu1 and just not render that out, and return just the children:

```
<% loop $Menu(1) %>
    <% loop $Children %>
        <li class="$LinkingMode"><a href="$Link" title="$Title.XML">$MenuTitle.XML</a></li>
    <% end_loop %>
<% end_loop %>
```

If you want them in the li of each you can add them similarly there:

```
<% loop $Menu(1) %>
    <li class="$LinkingMode"><a href="$Link" title="$Title.XML">$MenuTitle.XML</a>
        <% if $Children %>
            <ul>
            <% loop $Children %>
                <li class="$LinkingMode"><a href="$Link" title="$Title.XML">$MenuTitle.XML</a></li>
            <% end_loop %>
            </ul>
        <% end_if %>
    </li>
<% end_loop %>
```